# Prevent SweetAlert2 from closing/dismissing from willClose?

Tags: javascript, dialog, sweetalert2

Sorry if I am missing something from the documentation but I can't find anyway to prevent a dialog from closing in SweetAlert 2, these won't work:

```
        await Swal.fire({
            html: diagHtml,
            showCancelButton: true,

            willClose: (el) => {
                console.log(el);

                if (someLogic()) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            },
        });
```

Is there a way to keep the dialog stay, preferably with `async`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't prevent dialog from closing with willClose, maybe the following code can be your alternative:

```
await Swal.fire({
  html: diagHtml,
  showDenyButton: true,
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  allowEscapeKey: false,
  preConfirm: () => {
    if (someLogic()) {
      return false; // Prevent confirmed
    }
  },
  preDeny: () => {
    if (someLogic()) {
      return false; // Prevent denied
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I didn't notice these two options. Will try and tell you if it works.